# python auto-py-to-exe not adding images

Tags: python, image, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to get a 1 exe file from a python script.
i use Tkinter for the layout.

When trying to add the images i get strange error's i don't know how to solve.

```
icon_path = './icon.png'
logo_path = './logo.png'

icon = (tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_path))
root.iconphoto(False, icon)

logo = (tk.PhotoImage(file=logo_path))
shrink_factor = 3
width, height = logo.width(), logo.height()
new_width, new_height = width // shrink_factor, height // shrink_factor
resized_logo = logo.subsample(shrink_factor, shrink_factor)

logolabel = tk.Label(root, image=resized_logo)
logolabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
```

When i run auto-py-to-exe i use the following

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-binary "C:/logo.png;." --add-binary "C:/icon.png;."  "C:/main.py"
```

the proces is running correctly but the file itself gives a error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 329, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4130, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4075, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "./icon.png": no such file or directory
```

if i add the icon to the same folder as the exe file it is working but i want it to be in the same exe file not as single files.

i tried changing the path to

```
icon_path = 'icon.png'
logo_path = 'logo.png'
```

but got a simular error message.

Could you explain to me how to add the image to the exe file without the exe file needing the images in a (sub)folder?

Kind regards

Comment: `--add-binary "C:/logo.png;." --add-binary "C:/icon.png;."` You used `;` instead of `:` as src/dst delimiter. Unrelated, but I'd considering using `--add-data` instead.